# UNION ALL w/ MINUS

Tags: oracle, minus

Why does:

```
select 1 FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL
select 1 FROM DUAL
MINUS
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
```

return only a single `1` rather than 2 rows of `1` in Oracle?

Answer (score 7):

In Oracle all set operators currently [have equal precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm) and are evaluated from top to bottom.

```
SELECT 1
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 1
FROM   DUAL;
```

Returns two rows with both columns containing 1.

But `minus` operates similarly to `union` (as opposed to `union all`) and removes duplicates so `distinct`-ifying the result.

One way of getting the result you want would be to add parentheses so that `(1)` is `Union all`-ed onto the result of `(1) MINUS (2)`.

```
SELECT 1
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
(SELECT 1
 FROM   DUAL
 MINUS
 SELECT 2
 FROM   DUAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Martin Smith addressed a possible solution if you don't need to union before you minus (which I'm not sure will work for what you intend)..  If you need to `UNION` first before you `MINUS`, while still preserving duplicate rows, then I think you'll have to do something along these lines:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT 1 as col1 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 as col1 FROM DUAL) UN
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 2 as col1 FROM DUAL MI WHERE UN.col1 = MI.col1)
```

Essentially doing the `UNION ALL` and then filtering the result (via `WHERE` clause) to exclude any that exist in your `MINUS` data set.

Comment: I agree this answer does seem likely to be more useful if the OP has some practical case in mind that inspired the question.

Comment: *nods*  I failed to notice, at the time, that he asked "why" instead of "how to"..  Your answer perfectly answers "why".  :)